# How to determine capacity of blank inserted burnable optical media (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray disc) from Windows command line or batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, capacity, optical-drive

Is there a way to determine the type and size of blank inserted burnable media from Windows command prompt / batch file?

I know with hard disk / SSD I can use:

```
WMIC logicaldisk get deviceid, size, freespace
```

and extract information I need. But for optical media, I can't seem to find anything that would relate to what capacity or type of media is inserted.

I thought that `DriveType` and `MediaType` fields might be a way, but it doesn't seem so specific.

`DriveType = 3` and `MediaType = 12` for hard drive or SSD

`DriveType = 5` and `MediaType = 11` for optical media regardless of media type (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray /M-Disc 25, 50, 100GB).

`Freespace` and `Size` fields are completely blank for optical media

From command line, if I switch to the drive letter with the burnable media (i.e. `G: <ENTER>`), it just gives error `Incorrect function.`

From Windows Explorer I can do a right click - properties of the optical drive, and shows me free space. But I can't seem to find a way directly from the command line.

Anyone know if there is another way?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that the information about the capacity of an unwritten/blank optical disk is available to WMI.

Comment: It seems that may be the case. :(